# Downloading python packages (example: beautifulsoup4)

Tags: python, cmd, beautifulsoup

When I type something like in the command prompt :

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Why doesn't it install in the scripts folder where I have the directory set? (i.e)

```
L:/Code/Scripts
```

I can never find these packages once I install them and I don't know why. They seem to be installing in a different location, and this is true any time I've downloaded a package.  They go to random places.  Thanks.

Comment: There isn't much of an use to know the path of the installed library, `pip` will install it under it's Python version path, but you don't need this knowledge to use the library in Python.

Answer (score 0):

When you install with pip, it installs the package into site-packages folder under your python distribution. Try to look for `python-location\Lib\site-package`

Comment: But it seems like I can't use the module associated with the package.  When calling my python file, it is saying, "No module named BS4" (beautiful Soup).  The line in question in my code is: from BS4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 What does is say?

Comment: And, in checking my scripts folder (set to this in my current directory) there is the folder: beautifulsoup4-4.0.0b3 .  Not sure what's up here.

Comment: So,Yuan Fu - you are correct it was in that folder.  Once I copy bs4 from site-package, into my scripts folder, it doesn't give me the error.  So it must be that the package must be in the directory in which it is called from?

Comment: That works, you can check this site about importing in python. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path  Basically you can import modules either from local directory or from the directory that is in path